# How many feeds should be in our main chat?

Tags: discussion, chat

At present we have a lot of useful feeds of network wide questions to our chat room that may be of interest:

> <sup>Recent Questions - German Language Meta Stack Exchange posted by German Language Meta
>
>   Newest questions tagged german - Linguistics Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged German on Linguistics SE
>
>   Active questions tagged german - English Language & Usage Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged German on English Language
>
>   Newest questions tagged german - English Language Learners Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged German on ELL SE
>
>   Newest questions tagged allemand - French Language Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged German on French SE
>
>   Active questions tagged germany - Expatriates Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Germany on Expatriates
>
>   Active questions tagged germany - Law Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Germany on Law
>
>   Active questions tagged germany - Skeptics Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Germany on Skeptics
>
>   Newest questions tagged austria - Travel Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Austria on Travel
>
>   Featured Questions - German Language Stack Exchange posted by Kopfgeldjäger
>
>   Newest questions tagged switzerland - Skeptics Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Switzerland on Skeptics
>
>   Newest questions tagged austria - Law Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Austria on Law
>
>   Newest questions tagged switzerland - Expatriates Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Switzerland on Expatriates
>
>   Newest questions tagged austria - Expatriates Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Austria on Expatriates
>
>   Active questions tagged german - Language Learning Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged German on Language Learning SE
>
>   Newest questions tagged german-language - Travel Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged German Language on Travel
>
>   Newest questions tagged switzerland - Travel Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Switzerland on Travel
>
>   Newest questions tagged liechtenstein - Travel Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Liechtenstein on Travel
>
>   Active questions tagged german-citizens - Expatriates Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged German Citizens on Expatriates
>
>   Active questions tagged germany - Travel Stack Exchange posted by Questions tagged Germany on Travel</sup>

Now these feeds fill up our chat considerably. At times there is not much more than feed posts **over weeks**. This may have the following unwanted side effects:

- New users may get the impression that our chat is an advertising board for network questions rather than a place for discussion among users.
- Other users may find it harder to read conversations between those many feeds.
- Announcements we make regarding our own site may get lost or are much harder to see.
- We are dragging people away from German Language by feeding much more questions of other sites.

In addition most feeded questions (e.g from Travel, Expatriates, or Law) turned out to be only marginally (if at all) related to language and would be off topic for the site.

Do we need to reduce the amount of feeds? If so, which feeds should we keep, which feeds are superfluous?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have noticed the feed-filled chat quite a few times now and I was never really sure whether I liked it or not. Each of the feeds we have is, unfortunately, an entire chat post posted by a bot which makes them unmissable.

In the impression I get from other chats, feeds should mainly be there to notify users that potentially interesting questions were asked somewhere. This is great for questions that the German.SE userbase could find interesting and answerable but were asked e.g. on Linguistics.SE. But if it ends up that ‘only the bots are doing the talking’, that somewhat defeats the purpose.

What I have noticed from using the [Periodic Table](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table) a lot, is that most feeds there are not a bot post but turn up in the downward-sliding top notification bar, the way new questions to the site are also added. In the [Periodic Table](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3229/the-periodic-table), this features questions tagged [chemistry](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/chemistry) on both the physics and the biology site. It does have the downside that it only shows up to those people currently in the room. But still, I think that would be a much better idea than the bot-post feeds.

Thus I propose:

- Keep feeds on language-site questions in their present format — Language Learning, Linguistics and potentially the other language sites (ELU/ELL, French, etc.) jump to mind.
- For all other feeds, introduce the drop-down feed type rather than the bot-post type.

Comment: Since nobody seems to be in favour of a more lenient answer, I realised this suggestion for now. This does not mean that this is final; we can always take more drastic measures should they be in favour. But since everybody seems to agree to at least do this, I saw no reason to delay action.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You meant to say ‘more strict answer’. This is the most lenient answer second only to [keep all feeds](http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/a/1202). ;)

Comment: *You meant to say ‘more strict answer’.* – Nope. Everybody is in favour of this or a more strict answer; nobody is in favour of a more lenient answer.

Comment: Oh that’s what you wanted to say?

Answer (score 2):

To reduce the clutter in our main chat room I propose the following:

- Completely remove message feeds of questions from **non-language sites** travel, expatriates, law, and skeptics.

  > Users who wish to further get noticed of questions on these sites are encouraged to subscribe to the tags [germany](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/germany) [austria](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/austria) [switzerland](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/switzerland) [liechtenstein](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/liechtenstein) there.
- Move all tags [german](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/german) from **language site** feeds (from language learning, linguistics, english, english learners) to the ticker feed where they will appear next to the unchanged new question feed of our own site.
- Only keep our own new meta posts feed and the featured question feed as a message feed to the chat room.

Answer (score -2):

Leave all feeds as they are.

> Users who do not wish to see any of these feeds are encouraged to hide posts of an offending feed bot.

Answer (score -3):

Do not post any feeds to our general chat room.